# JavaScript table search by dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

Untill now i have always used the same type of method to sort tables dynamicly:

```
function sortTableByLevel(level)
{
    $('.data_table_row').each(function()
    {
            var table_level = parseInt($(this).find('.avg_level').text());
            if(table_level >= level)
            {
                $(this).show();
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }
    });

}
```

But recently i encountered the following problem:

*What if you have several parameters that you wish to search at the same time*

Then the above function would not work because if you had a similar function it would just sort by the last one selected.

So my question is what is "best pratice" or even how do you deal with the problem of several parameters being searched by the user in a table?

**my table**

```
<table class="table table-striped b-t b-light" id="data_table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Titel</th>
    <th>Kompetence</th>
    <th>Gns niveau</th>
    <th>Gap</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="data_body">
<?php if (isset($vars['table_data'])): ?>
    <?php foreach ($vars['table_data'] as $data): ?>
        <?php foreach($data['attributes'] as $attribute):?>
            <tr class="data_table_row">
                <td class="title_name" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php echo utf8_encode($data['name']); ?></td>
                <td class="attribute"
                    id="attribute_id_<?php echo $attribute['attribute_id']; ?>"><?php echo $attribute['name'] ?></td>
                <td class="avg_level"><?php echo $attribute['avg'] ?></td>
                <td class="gap_level"><span class="<?php if($attribute['gap'] < 0){echo 'text-danger';}else{echo 'text-success';}?>"><?php echo $attribute['gap'] ?><span></td>

            </tr>

        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

**My inputs**

```
<div class="row wrapper">
<div class="col-sm-6 m-b-xs">
    <select class="input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline pull-right" id="select_attribute">
        <option value="0">Vælg kompetence</option>
        <?php if (isset($vars['attribute_list'])): ?>
            <?php foreach ($vars['attribute_list'] as $attribute): ?>
                <option
                    value="<?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>"><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select class="input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline v-middle pull-right" id="select_level">
        <option value="0">Vælg niveau</option>
        <option value="1">Niveau 1</option>
        <option value="2">Niveau 2</option>
        <option value="3">Niveau 3</option>
        <option value="4">Niveau 4</option>
        <option value="5">Niveau 5</option>
        <option value="6">Niveau 6</option>
        <option value="7">Niveau 7</option>
        <option value="8">Niveau 8</option>
        <option value="9">Niveau 9</option>
        <option value="10">Niveau 10</option>

    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" onclick="showAll()"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on how the sorting is done and what type of data it is. For example, would it be possible to me to sort by the largest and smallest item at the same time?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the sorting i am talking about is basicly you have select drop downs with values where each of the select is sortable with eachother so for instance level with name ect ect.

Comment: Why is the *data* stored in the DOM? That seems odd that the *view* is the *model*. Maybe have the data stored in JavaScript and only update the DOM to reflect the change in state. Easier to calculate sorting / filtering and saves needless and inefficient DOM manipulations

Comment: @Sukima think of it this way: the data is already collected by the model and processed by the view this is after the document has loaded and now i need to "filter" in the already collected result

Comment: `$(this).find('.avg_level').text()` means, you've loaded the data in the *model* written the data to the DOM, ignored the data in memory and read back from the DOM to filter. Hence your using the DOM as your storage back end and that was what I was commenting on.

Comment: @Sukima ive posted my table structure (with php and all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple inputs have `level` be an array of items and then loop through each item and check `table_level >= level[i]` This would check that if a single `level[i]` was lower than or the equal to `table_level` then show your element:

```
$('.data_table_row').each(function()
{
        var table_level = parseInt($(this).find('.avg_level').text());
        var show = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < level.length; ++i) 
            if( table_level >= level[i] ) 
                show = true;

        if(show) 
            $(this).show();
        else 
            $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: can you check my above code ( table and input fields) '

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best approach. The for loop drastically confused me. Can you explain it's need over looping over the known `.avg_level` elements?

Comment: @Sukima The OP wanted to compare a series of separate `level`'s with the current `table_level` element that they are searching for.  `level` is an array contained a series of different levels. Basically if we looped through `.avg_level` we would still need to loop through the series of search parameters to compare that to.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have PHP, JavaScript and jQuery. I would approach it this way:

#### PHP

Construct the markup and add proper data to the markup and don't rely on the text content which is not query-able:

```
<?php foreach($data['attributes'] as $attribute):?>
<tr class="data_table_row" data-average="<?=$attribute['avg']?>">
  <!-- ... -->
  <td class="avg_level numeric"><?=$attribute['avg']?></td>
  <!-- ... -->
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

#### JavaScript

Leverage the power of jQuery's query language and have it toggle a class. Handle the show / hide in CSS

```
function filterRows(levels) {
  $('.avg-level').each(function(el) {
    var avg   = $(el).data('average');
    var shown = levels.some(function(level) {
      return (avg >= level);
    });
    $(el).toggleClass('hidden', !shown);
  });
}
```

#### CSS

And since all elements with class `hidden` should hide:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

### Example:

```js
function filterAverage(levels) {
  $('.data_table_row').each(function(index, el) {
    var average = $(el).data('average');
    var shown   = levels.some(function(level) {
      return (average >= level);
    });
    $(el).toggleClass('hidden', !shown);
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#levelChooser').on('keyup', function() {
    var levels = $(this).val()
      .trim()
      .split(' ')
      .map(function(level) {
        return parseInt(level, 10);
      })
      .filter(function(level) {
        return !isNaN(level);
      });
    filterAverage(levels.length === 0 ? [0] : levels);
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="levelChooser">Level:</label>
<input type="text" id="levelChooser">

<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="data_table_row" data-average="1">
        <td class="avg_level">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data_table_row" data-average="2">
        <td class="avg_level">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data_table_row" data-average="3">
        <td class="avg_level">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data_table_row" data-average="4">
        <td class="avg_level">4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data_table_row" data-average="5">
        <td class="avg_level">5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data_table_row" data-average="6">
        <td class="avg_level">6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```